# Need to create multiple files using a parameterized generic file and input file with parameter values using shell scripting

Tags: shell, awk, sed

Generic file content:

```
SELECT @a,
@b,
from @c;
```

input file content:
header-> @a,@b,@c,@d

```
colA1,ColB1,Table1,File1
colA2,ColB2,Table2,File2
colA3,ColB3,Table3,File3
```

.
.

Final output should be files with File name as File1,File2, and so on.. and it should have data as below,

FILE1 should have:

```
SELECT ColA1,
ColB1,
from Table1;
```

.
.

FILE100:

```
SELECT ColA100,
ColB100,
from Table100;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    fmt = fmt $0 ORS
    next
}
FNR==1 {
    gsub(/@[[:alpha:]]/,"%s",fmt)
    FS = ","
    $0 = $0
}
{
    printf fmt, $1, $2, $3 > $4
    close($4)
}

$ awk -f tst.awk config file

$ for f in File*; do echo "--------$f"; cat "$f"; done
--------File1
SELECT colA1,
ColB1,
from Table1;
--------File2
SELECT colA2,
ColB2,
from Table2;
--------File3
SELECT colA3,
ColB3,
from Table3;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. this is working exactly as I required.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** Since OP is saying to read field values from a generic file then following may help here.

Let's say following is generic file as follows:

```
cat generic
SELECT 1,
2,
from 3;
```

Run following code.

```
awk -v s1=",\n"  '
FNR==NR{
  sub(/,$/,"")
  a[FNR]=$NF
  next
}
{
  close(file)
  print "SELECT " $a[1] s1 $a[2] s1 "from " $a[3]";" > ($NF)
  file=$NF
}'  generic FS=","  Input_file
```

Output will be `File1`, `File2` etc.

---

---

Could you please try following. It will create output files named like `File1`, `File2` etc.

```
awk -v s1=",\n"  -F, '{close(file);print "SELECT " $1 s1 $2 s1 "from " $3";" > ($NF);file=$NF}' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution here.

```
awk -v s1=",\n"  -F, '
{
  close(file)
  print "SELECT " $1 s1 $2 s1 "from " $3";" > ($NF)
  file=$NF
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: in above suggestion we are using content of generic file as part of print block but my requirement is to read the content from generic file as it may change.

Comment: @Wasif, not clear code is written as per your shown sample. If it is not the one which is providing you correct answer then please ADD samples in your post of input and expected output and let us know then.

Comment: Thanks for the solution provided earlier. the code will work fine if the content of generic file is fixed so that we can write the print block accordingly. but I am looking for the solution where we are reading the file content from generic file and replacing the parameter with its value from input file instead of writing the print block manually.

Comment: @Wasif, could you please provide example for your statement once? It is not clear to me.

Comment: I have also tried with this script which is working similar to your solution. awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} {print "SEL "$1",\n"$2",\nfrom "$3 > $4 }' input

Comment: But what if generic file has more than 1k line of text, it wont be feasible to write the content of generic file in the script. is there anyway we can fetch content from generic file itself instead of writing the content in script.

Comment: @Wasif, please check my EDIT solution now? which reads field values to form a sql query from file named `generic` and reads actual Input_file to create queries then. Let me know how it goes then?